# Javascript Importing images into Photoshop by its alphabetical and numerical order

Tags: javascript, photoshop

This is a javascript (not mine) that imports images into Photoshop by its alphabetical and numerical order.

When script runs:

-User selects folder of images to import into Photoshop.

-Images then imported in by its alphabetical and numerical order. EX:

> a.01.png, b.01.png, c.01.png, a.02.png, b.02.png, c.02.png, a.03.png,
>   b.03.png, c.03.png
>   ..etc.

Script works great until it gets to the end. It always fails to bring in one of the images from the last numerical set. EX of failure:

> a.01.png, b.01.png, c.01.png, a.02.png, b.02.png, c.02.png,
>
> “Skips bringing in a.03.png here”
>
> b.03.png, c.03.png

Doesn’t matter how many number of sets, the very last set always fails to import one image.  The rest import fine. I haven’t been able to figure out what causes this. Anybody able to find the issue in this script below?

### Update

I didn't mention that this is a segment of code out of a much larger JavaScript so the PSDcreate and other items are used elsewhere. I just cropped out the segment that was failing since the original is too large to post. I ran the script you created and it does bring them in but not quite the way they do in the code it I have. I believe yours brings in the images

> a.00.1png, a.002.png, a.003.png b.001.png, b.002.png, b.003.png, c.001.png, c.002.png, c.003.png...ect

The one I am using puts in in order of

> a.001.png, b.001.png, c.001.png, a.002.png, b.002.png, c.002png
>    ...etc

I have the a,b,c images ending in .001 imported into Photoshop first. Then at that point the code I took out then stacks the images in order (a,b,c) and does various other tasks. When done, saves them out as a PSD file "name.001.psd". Then the script brings in the next group of images with 002 and repeats the process in a loop. That's the part I removed because its so much code and didn't seem to be the issue. Is it possible to have the images brought in by

> a,b,c of .001, then a,b,c of .002..etc?

Code:

```
#target photoshop
app.bringToFront();

// Dialog for user to choose folder of documents to process
var inputFolderArray = [];
do {  
var inputFolder = Folder.selectDialog("Select a folder of documents to process");  
if(inputFolder != null) {
      inputFolderArray.push(inputFolder);
    }
}
while(inputFolder != null
|| inputFolder != undefined)

// Pulls images from inputFolder
for (var j = 0; j < inputFolderArray.length; j++) {
  var filesList = inputFolderArray[j].getFiles();

var outputDirectory = inputFolderArray[j] + '/';

// Sort the order of files corresponding to the number
  filesList.sort(function(x,y) {

// the substr gets the numbers (ex: get "01" from image.01.png)
var xp = (x.name).substr(-6, 2);
    var yp = (y.name).substr(-6, 2);
return parseInt(xp) - parseInt(yp);
  });
  var frameArrays = [[]];
var oldFrameNum = (filesList[0].name).substr(-6, 2);

// These are used for array slice
  var arrayStartNum = 0;
  var arrayEndNum = 1;

// Put each frame into separate array
  for (var i = 1; i < filesList.length; i++) {

var currentFrameNum = (filesList[i].name).substr(-6, 2);
    if(oldFrameNum !== currentFrameNum) {
      oldFrameNum = currentFrameNum;
      frameArrays[0].push(filesList.slice(arrayStartNum, i));
      arrayStartNum = i;
      arrayEndNum = i-1;
    }
    else if(i === filesList.length-1) {
      frameArrays[0].push(filesList.slice(arrayStartNum, i));
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < frameArrays[0].length; i++) {

// Sort the file order alphabetically
    sorter = MySort('*!@_.()#^&%-=+01234567989abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
    frameArrays[0][i].sort(sorter)
    PSDCreate(frameArrays[0][i], outputDirectory);
  }
}


// FUNCTIONS BELOW//
function PSDCreate(frameArrays, outputDirectory) {
  directory = outputDirectory + '/';

//var outputLocation = inputFolder + "/" + directory;
  var outputFileName = '';
  if (frameArrays != null) {

// Get all the files in the folder
    var fileList = frameArrays;
    var k = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
      if (fileList[i] instanceof File && fileList[i].hidden == false) {

var fileName = fileList[i].name;
        var docRef = open(fileList[i]);

        if(k == 0) {
          k++;
          outputFileName = RemoveExtension(docRef.name);
        }
      }
    } 
  }
}

// Removes extension from file name
function RemoveExtension(name) {
  var fileNameNoExtension = name;
  fileNameNoExtension = fileNameNoExtension.split(".");
  if ( fileNameNoExtension.length > 1 ) {
    fileNameNoExtension.length--;
  }
  fileNameNoExtension = fileNameNoExtension.join(".");
  return fileNameNoExtension;
}

// Sort the file order alphabetically with special characters
function MySort(alphabet)
{
    return function(a, b) { 
var index_a = alphabet.indexOf(a[0]),
        index_b = alphabet.indexOf(b[0]);
        if (index_a === index_b) {

// same first character, sort regular
            if (a < b) {
                return -1;
            } else if (a > b) {
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        } else {
            return index_a - index_b;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to figure out why you lose one of the array elements: your sorting was quite puzzling to me, so I rewrote sort, I think it's a bit easier to read. I first extract all the information I need to sort from file path (prefix, number) and put it to a temporary array (along with anything I need to open this path later). The I sort this array by prefix and number. Also I replaced `PSDCreate` with `app.open` because question was about opening files in a specific order, `PSDCreate` contains a lot of irrelevant info.

```
var filesArray = [],
    parsedFilesArray = [];

// Dialog for user to choose folder of documents to process
var inputFolderArray = [];

do {
    var inputFolder = Folder.selectDialog("Select a folder of documents to process");
    if (inputFolder != null)
    {
        inputFolderArray.push(inputFolder);
    }
}
while (inputFolder != null ||
    inputFolder != undefined)

// create an array of objects to sort it later based on files from InputFolder
for (var j = 0; j < inputFolderArray.length; j++)
{
    var filesList = inputFolderArray[j].getFiles();
    for (var i = 0; i < filesList.length; i++)
    {
        //extracting values for an object: [1] == path, [2] == name, [3] == number;
        var fileString = String(filesList[i]).match(/(.*)(?:\/)(.*?)\.(\d*)\.(.*)/);

        parsedFilesArray.push(
        {
            key: fileString[2], //filename
            num: fileString[3], //01
            path: fileString[1], // c/path/to/file/
            file: [fileString[2], fileString[3], "png"].join(".") // filename.01.png
        })
    }
}

//sorting the array
parsedFilesArray.sort(function(a, b)
{
    if (a.key === b.key)
    {
        return parseInt(a.num) - parseInt(b.num);
    }
    return a.key > b.key ? 1 : -1;
})

//opening files from the sorted array
for (var i = 0; i < parsedFilesArray.length; i++)
{
    app.open(new File(parsedFilesArray[i].path + "/" + parsedFilesArray[i].file))
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to have it come in by a,b,c 001.png, a,b,c 002,png..etc instead of a.001.png, a.002.png, a.003.png, b.001.png, b.002.png, b.003.png..etc? I added to my comment above with better explanation.